# What does the ending mean?

Tags: first-squad

At the end of First Squad,

> The ghosts attack the Russian army to steal this artifact (can't remember what it was) but at the last moment, they change their attack. It looks like me the whole attack was a decoy, but for what? The movie ends soon after, without telling the whole story.

So what happened?